# no printing result shown below the cell when working with jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I downgrade VS Code from 1.87 to 1.69 since 1.87 is very slow and 1.69 is very fast for a large jupyter notebook.

But the problem is there is no printing result shown below the cell after execting the cell?

Anyone has idea on how to enable showing printing result below each cell? Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you ran. There may be no output for certain cells. You'd have to provide examples of code cells. Like a `print('Hello World.')`? Does the asterisk ever go away from the cells involved as if it completes execution?

Comment: Thanks Wayne, yes I do have print() and it just didn't print the result. When I used newer version of 1.87, everything is fine.